# Where did the "move to" option go when selecting multiple emails from a search in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I used to be able to search and then select multiple emails them move them to a folder (which removed them from my inbox). Did that feature get deleted from Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

The button was recently removed from this particular scenario, but you are still able to drag & drop your selected emails:

[image]